# Scale font to a desired x-height/em/cap-height/etc' in fontspec

Tags: fontspec

When reproducing a typographic layout from print I often run into the usual difficulty of a font's "point size" not being easily measureable on a page.
On the other hand, features such as x-height and cap-height are easy to measure but fontspec doesn't accept them as a size specification (as far as I know).

IOW, is something like `\newfontface[xheight=<dim>]{EB Garamond}` available?

Comment: Could you give an example or two of what you have in mind? You probably now that `fontspec` provides the `Scale=<some positive scalar>` option. However, from the description you've given so far I can'te tell if this option might be useful for you.

Comment: How do I get "EB Garamond at a point size such that x-height=4.78pt" with fontspec?

Comment: @JaredKulik May be that's not a job for `fontspec` but for the font size of the document?

Comment: As you probably know, the "x-height" of a font and the height of the letter `x` are not always identical. E.g., for `EB Garamond`, the x-height is `4.0pt` whereas the height of the (roman/upright) letter `x` is `4.05pt`. Thus, measuring the heights of uppercase and lowercase letters may not give you the font's caps height and x-height, respectively.

Comment: Actually, I had hoped that wasn't the case but at least the delta should be reasonably small and good enough for a starting point, measurements invariably have an error component as well after all.

Comment: Nice idea! <https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/210>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you're using LuaTeX. If so, one can set up a macro called `\Setxheight` and use it with `fontspec`'s `Scale` option. Note that the macro uses Lua's division routine instead of TeX's own built-in routine since the scaling factor will likely not be integer-valued.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%% x-height of font is stored in \fontdimen5
\newcommand\Setxheight[1]{\directlua{%
    tex.sprint(#1/(\the\numexpr\dimexpr 
    \the\fontdimen5\font\relax\relax/65536))}}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\the\fontdimen5\font  % show value of x-height

\setmainfont[Scale=\Setxheight{4.78}]{EB Garamond} % reload the font

\the\fontdimen5\font % show value of x-height
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: XeLaTeX version

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%% x-height of font is stored in \fontdimen5
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\Setxheight[1]{
\fp_eval:n{(#1/(\the\numexpr\dimexpr 
\the\fontdimen5\font\relax\relax/65536))}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\the\fontdimen5\font  % show value of x-height

\setmainfont[Scale=\Setxheight{4.78}]{EB Garamond} % reload the font

\the\fontdimen5\font % show value of x-height
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works fine. Can you manage a xetex version for completeness?

Comment: @JaredKulik - I'm afraid I don't know how to do division arithmetic in XeTeX. Maybe a more knowledgeable person will jump in and provide a parallel answer.

Comment: @JaredKulik — Untested: replace `\directlua{tex.sprint(` by `\fp_eval:n{(` and surround the definition of `Setxheight` in `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: Yup, that works.